# What's the meaning of "drop" in mathematics?

Tags: terminology

What's the meaning of "drop" in following sentence:

> "the term can be dropped from the numerator"

Comment: Removed I guess, depending on the context

Comment: You'd have to give. More specific context to be sure, but yes, ignored or eliminated, depending on context.

Comment: There is no specific use of "drop" in mathematics. Sometimes it is used in sentences as "we can drop this hypothesis". I have no idea on what would be the meaning in "drop from the denominator".

Comment: Some additional context would greatly improve the answerability of this question. What's the fractional expression? Which "term" is being "dropped"?

Comment: More detail is needed and I cannot say for sure but I take the word dropped to mean ignored by choice and not by removed by some process such as cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

"Dropped" just means deleted.  If the numerator is $A+B+C$ and one replaces it with $A+B$, one has dropped the third term from the numerator.